# Feeding list of tf.truncated_normal() or list of dictionaries into a Tensorflow Model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and I am trying to learn how to use the tool efficiently.

I expand on the question below but here is the tldr:

I am wondering what is the best way to feed the following weights and biases into my model with feed_dict:

```
def generate_initial_population(my_population_size):
    my_weights = []
    my_biases = []
    for _ in range(my_population_size):
        my_weights.append({
            'h1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_inputs, n_hidden_1])),
            'h2': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
            'out': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_2, n_class]))
        })

        my_biases.append({
            'b1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_1])),
            'b2': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_2])),
            'out': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_class]))
        })
    return my_weights, my_biases


weights, biases = generate_initial_population(population_size)
```

I cannot simply use `feed_dict={weights_ph: weights}` because it will generate errors. I do not know how to deal with this problem efficiently

Examining the code at the end might help with understanding what i am talking about.

I am wondering if there is any way I could feed a list containing tf.truncated_normals to my model. 
I get the `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` error because I believe it is trying to convert to np.array but has issues with the dimensions

I have found an easy workout where i figure out the values of all the tensors first with session run and then feed that into my model. 
I am just confused if this is the right solution since I would be inclined to  believe it is slower because you have to execute session twice?

This solution also doesnt work however if my original list is not perfect shape
like `[ [1, [1,2]]]` or when my truncated_normals do not have the same shapes

I was thinking im just going to feed my weird shape list into my model and then use tf.gather to get the specific indexes I want to work on.

Since i cannot do that is my solution the proper way to deal with this... simply calculating the truncated_normals first and then feeding that into the model. then reshaping the list while inside the model if you need to?

I also am having a very similar problems because I wanted to feed in a list of dictionaries into the model as well. Is the proper way of dealing with that to extract the data from dictionaries and then just feed in each value from each key separately.

I am trying to learn and i couldnt find this information elsewhere

Here is a code snippet i designed to fail to explain what i mean

```
import tensorflow as tf

list_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
index_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)


def model(my_list, index):
    value = tf.gather(my_list, index, axis=0)
    return value



my_model = model(list_ph, index_ph)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    var_list = []

    truncated_normal = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[5, 3]))

    for i in range(4):
        var_list.append(truncated_normal)
    # for i in range(4):
    #     var_list.append({i: i*2})


    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    #will work but will not work for dictionaries
    val = sess.run(var_list)
    # will not work, but will work if you feed val
    var = sess.run(my_model, feed_dict={list_ph: var_list, index_ph: 1})
```

Comment: Can you simplify this question/post? Please, ONE question per POST, if possible!! I got confused when I got to the 4th paragraph.

Comment: @nbro Hey sorry for the confusion. I edited the question with the tldr which should be much simpler to understand

Comment: I found this documentation but I have no idea if it is helpful in any way:https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lookup/HashTable